# Sprite text getting cut off

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am using Extjs 5 for generating a chart.
I have added a sprite text to the chart, but I am unable to wrap the text for long string values.

The issue is shown in the image.[image]
Here is the code for sprite.

```
        sprites: [{
            type: 'text',
            text: '',
            textAlign: 'left',
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            //width: 50,
            //height: 30,
            x: 100, 
            y: 10,
            'fill': '#333f49'               
        }],
```

I am setting the text value dynamically from controller.
Is there any way I can wrap the text to next line for long string values?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The text sprite doesn't auto-wrap. But it does take into account line breaks. So what you need to do is insert line breaks yourself.

You can use the `Ext.util.TextMetrics` class to determine how long the text is, and then find a suitable whitespace character to replace with a new line.